# How to populate multi object json data as html table using php /jquiry?

Tags: php, json

I have a (PHP cURL) Shipment Tracking API from [Rapidapi](https://rapidapi.com/colinnn/api/order-tracking/). the code i have to place in my website is below.

```
=== the api code received from rapidapi ===
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://order-tracking.p.rapidapi.com/trackings/realtime",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n    \"tracking_number\": \"CM419380522IN \",\n    \"carrier_code\": \"india-post\"\n}",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "content-type: application/json",
        "x-rapidapi-host: order-tracking.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key: <YOUR-RAPID-API-KEY>"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}else {
    echo $response;
}
```

when I save this code in php file and refresh the page I get the result like:

[default result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpAqq.png)

```
=== api result ===
{"meta":{"code":200,"type":"Success","message":"Success"},"data":{"items":[{"id":"88ccbd9812965e638ffc868a0783fed4","tracking_number":"CM419380522IN","carrier_code":"india-post","order_create_time":"","destination_code":"","status":"transit","track_update":true,"original_country":"India","itemTimeLength":9,"stayTimeLength":2,"service_code":null,"packageStatus":null,"substatus":null,"last_mile_tracking_supported":null,"origin_info":{"ItemReceived":"2021-09-20 15:56:31","ItemDispatched":null,"DepartfromAirport":null,"ArrivalfromAbroad":null,"CustomsClearance":null,"DestinationArrived":null,"weblink":"http:\/\/www.indiapost.gov.in\/","phone":null,"carrier_code":"india-post","trackinfo":[{"StatusDescription":"Item Received","Date":"2021-09-28 11:07:30","Details":"Timarni S.O","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Dispatched","Date":"2021-09-25 17:40:05","Details":"ITARSI RS TMO","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit002"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Received","Date":"2021-09-25 16:54:35","Details":"citynameS RS TMO","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Dispatched","Date":"2021-09-25 16:47:10","Details":"citynameS PH","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit002"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Bagged","Date":"2021-09-25 16:45:58","Details":"Itarsi PH","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Received","Date":"2021-09-25 13:36:10","Details":"Itarsi PH","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Dispatched","Date":"2021-09-24 20:01:58","Details":"ITARSI RS TMO","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit002"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Received","Date":"2021-09-24 19:56:54","Details":"ITARSI RS TMO","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Dispatched","Date":"2021-09-24 15:35:18","Details":"Bhopal RS TMO","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit002"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Received","Date":"2021-09-24 15:23:42","Details":"Bhopal RS TMO","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Dispatched","Date":"2021-09-24 12:51:37","Details":"Bhopal PH","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit002"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Bagged","Date":"2021-09-24 11:35:34","Details":"Bhopal PH","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Received","Date":"2021-09-24 09:56:16","Details":"Bhopal PH","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Dispatched","Date":"2021-09-24 01:40:23","Details":"Bhopal RS TMO","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit002"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Received","Date":"2021-09-23 21:12:22","Details":"Bhopal RS TMO","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Dispatched","Date":"2021-09-22 22:07:24","Details":"Pune PH","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit002"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Bagged","Date":"2021-09-22 21:31:36","Details":"Pune PH","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},{"StatusDescription":"Item Received","Date":"2021-09-22 19:47:06","Details":"Pune PH","checkpoint_status":"transit","substatus":"transit001"},"substatus":"notfound001","checkpoint_status":"transit"}]},"destination_info":{"ItemReceived":null,"ItemDispatched":null,"DepartfromAirport":null,"ArrivalfromAbroad":null,"CustomsClearance":null,"DestinationArrived":null,"weblink":null,"phone":null,"carrier_code":null,"trackinfo":null},"lastEvent":"Item Received,Timarni S.O,2021-09-28 11:07:30","lastUpdateTime":"2021-09-28 11:07:30"}]}}
```

so I want to get the above data (json/array) into an html table and I want to change the tracking id from `CM419380522IN` to `<?php echo $tracking_id; ?>` php string, so it will change dynamically.

I have tried converting the above data into array and tried to populate in table using the code below but got no success.

```
  $arr = json_decode($response, true);

//  echo "<pre>";
//  print_r($arr);
// echo "<pre>";

 echo '<table>';

 foreach ($arr as list ("id" => $id, "tracking_number" => $date, "Details" => $city, "checkpoint_status" => $status, "substatus" => $live,)) { 
    echo "<tr><td>{$id}</td><td>{$date}</td><td>{$city}</td><td>{$status}</td><td>{$live}</td></tr>";
 }
 
 echo '</table>';
```

`$arr  echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr); echo "<pre>";` result is like :

```
Array
(
    [meta] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [type] => Success
            [message] => Success
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 88ccbd9812965e638ffc868a0783fed4
                            [tracking_number] => CM419380522IN
                            [carrier_code] => india-post
                            [order_create_time] => 
                            [destination_code] => 
                            [status] => transit
                            [track_update] => 1
                            [original_country] => India
                            [itemTimeLength] => 10
                            [stayTimeLength] => 2
                            [service_code] => 
                            [packageStatus] => 
                            [substatus] => 
                            [last_mile_tracking_supported] => 
                            [origin_info] => Array
                                (
                                    [ItemReceived] => 2021-09-20 15:56:31
                                    [ItemDispatched] => 
                                    [DepartfromAirport] => 
                                    [ArrivalfromAbroad] => 
                                    [CustomsClearance] => 
                                    [DestinationArrived] => 
                                    [weblink] => http://www.indiapost.gov.in/
                                    [phone] => 
                                    [carrier_code] => india-post
                                    [trackinfo] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Received
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-28 11:07:30
                                                    [Details] => Timarni S.O
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Dispatched
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-25 17:40:05
                                                    [Details] => ITARSI RS TMO
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit002
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Received
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-25 16:54:35
                                                    [Details] => ITARSI RS TMO
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Dispatched
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-25 16:47:10
                                                    [Details] => Itarsi PH
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit002
                                                )

                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Bagged
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-25 16:45:58
                                                    [Details] => Itarsi PH
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                            [5] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Received
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-25 13:36:10
                                                    [Details] => Itarsi PH
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                            [6] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Dispatched
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-24 20:01:58
                                                    [Details] => ITARSI RS TMO
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit002
                                                )

                                            [7] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Received
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-24 19:56:54
                                                    [Details] => ITARSI RS TMO
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                            [8] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Dispatched
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-24 15:35:18
                                                    [Details] => Bhopal RS TMO
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit002
                                                )

                                            [9] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Received
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-24 15:23:42
                                                    [Details] => Bhopal RS TMO
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                            [10] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Dispatched
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-24 12:51:37
                                                    [Details] => Bhopal PH
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit002
                                                )

                                            [11] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Bagged
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-24 11:35:34
                                                    [Details] => Bhopal PH
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                            [12] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Received
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-24 09:56:16
                                                    [Details] => Bhopal PH
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                            [13] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Dispatched
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-24 01:40:23
                                                    [Details] => Bhopal RS TMO
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit002
                                                )

                                            [14] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Received
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-23 21:12:22
                                                    [Details] => Bhopal RS TMO
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                            [15] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Dispatched
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-22 22:07:24
                                                    [Details] => Pune PH
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit002
                                                )

                                            [16] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [StatusDescription] => Item Bagged
                                                    [Date] => 2021-09-22 21:31:36
                                                    [Details] => Pune PH
                                                    [checkpoint_status] => transit
                                                    [substatus] => transit001
                                                )

                                           

                                        )

                                )

                            [destination_info] => Array
                                (
                                    [ItemReceived] => 
                                    [ItemDispatched] => 
                                    [DepartfromAirport] => 
                                    [ArrivalfromAbroad] => 
                                    [CustomsClearance] => 
                                    [DestinationArrived] => 
                                    [weblink] => 
                                    [phone] => 
                                    [carrier_code] => 
                                    [trackinfo] => 
                                )

                            [lastEvent] => Item Received,Timarni S.O,2021-09-28 11:07:30
                            [lastUpdateTime] => 2021-09-28 11:07:30
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

[screenshot of $arr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnGvI.png)

How to populate this json data into html table?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the value of $arr won't be the array, but the object containing the object containing the array. What happens if you change the `$arr` in your foreach to `$arr['data']['items']`?

Comment: i get error when i use the $arr code.
Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\nx\htdocs\d\tracker.php on line 50

Notice: Undefined index: tracking_number in D:\nx\htdocs\d\tracker.php on line 50

Notice: Undefined index: Details in D:\nx\htdocs\d\tracker.php on line 50

Notice: Undefined index: checkpoint_status in D:\nx\htdocs\d\tracker.php on line 50

Notice: Undefined index: substatus in D:\nx\htdocs\d\tracker.php on line 50

Comment: Okay, I had a closer look at your JSON and I think I understand it now, but I don't understand what output you're expecting. Do you want a line for each item, or a line for each step of the tracking? You're requesting the id and the tracking number, which are parameters of the item, but then you're also requesting details and checkpoint status, which are parameters of the tracking step, meaning each item can contain 20+ different values for this. What exactly do you want your HTML table to display?

Comment: sir i want the [0] [1] [3] till the end tracking data in html table.

Comment: I want to see a line for each step of the tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I mentioned above, your array is not $arr, but a child of a child of $arr.

Second, not all the variables you request are actually children of the items array, some of them are children of multiple objects contained in an array that's a child of a child of your array.

Since you've specified in a comment that what you want outputted is every line of tracking, here's how you can do that:

```
$arr = json_decode($response, true);

// Now get the items array from $arr
$items = $arr['data']['items'];

echo '<table>';

// Loop through $items
foreach ($items as $item) {

    // Loop through $item['origin_info']['trackinfo']
    foreach ($item['origin_info']['trackinfo'] as $step) {
        echo '<tr>';

        // 'id' is an element of $item
        echo '<td>' . $item['id'] . '</td>';

        // 'tracking_number' is an element of $item
        echo '<td>' . $item['tracking_number'] . '</td>';

        // 'Details' is an element of $step
        echo '<td>' . $step['Details'] . '</td>';

        // 'checkpoint_status' is an element of $step
        echo '<td>' . $step['checkpoint_status'] . '</td>';

        // 'substatus' is an element of $step
        echo '<td>' . $step['substatus'] . '</td>';

    }


    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: thank you so much  for the code olafmoriarty sir. its showing the exact output as I wanted to see.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach() syntax is wrong, try :

```
$arr = json_decode($response, true);

echo '<table>';
$keys = array_keys($arr[0]) ;
foreach ($arr as $line){
echo "<tr>" ;
    foreach ($keys AS $key){
        echo "<td>{$line['$key']}</td>" ;
    }
    echo "</tr>" ;
}
 echo '</table>';
```

With this script, we catch all the columns with `$keys = array_keys($arr[0]) ;` so we can loop one the exact array keys (assuming all raws have same structure).

Comment: i am getting error : Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\nx\htdocs\d\tracker.php on line 39

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\nx\htdocs\d\tracker.php on line 39

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\nx\htdocs\d\tracker.php on line 42

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\nx\htdocs\d\tracker.php on line 42

Comment: sir kindly help me to get array / json in html table, i have added image results.
[The default result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpAqq.png) image files.
[The array i can see after json_decode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnGvI.png)